# How does LdapDistinguishedNameEncode work with the C# DirectoryServices library?

Tags: c#, ldap, sanitization

I'm trying to sanitize user input of an OU name for a C# application.

AntiXSS's `LdapDistinguishedNameEncode` appears to be custom-made for this, but when I try to use this on an OU's name, insert that into a distinguished name, and pass it into a `PrincipalContext` or `DirectoryEntry` object I get exceptions that the object cannot be found.

When using an un-sanitized OU name it all works successfully.

Do the AD libraries understand encoded distinguished names?  Or is the expectation that `LdapDistinguishedNameEncode` is meant to be run *before* OU creation as well as when referencing it later?

Sample code, where `ouName` is "Bob-Marley" or "dlanod's company" and the dashes and apostrophes get encoded:

```
        var distinguishedName = $"OU={Encoder.LdapDistinguishedNameEncode(ouName)},DC=sample,DC=net";

        try
        {
            // Create a context for the OU
            var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, _targetedUrl, distinguishedName, ContextOptions.Negotiate | ContextOptions.Signing | ContextOptions.Sealing);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.Error(e, "Organization {0} with definition {1} could not be found, exception occurred {2}", ouName, distinguishedName, e);
        }
```

Comment: did you ever find a good workaround for this?  I have a similar issue to your Bob-Marley example

Comment: Not a good workaround.  I've added the code I ended up adopting as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a workable approach that still let me use LdapDistinguishedNameEncode .

The code I adopted was:

```
        // Reject organization names with illegal or problematic characters (taken from RFC2253).
        // Used instead of Encoder.LdapDistinguishedNameEncode because of an expectation that
        // the creation passes through the same function.
        // https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5312.active-directory-characters-to-escape.aspx
        char[] illegalChars = {',', '\\', '#', '+', '<', '>', ';', '"', '='};
        if (name.IndexOfAny(illegalChars) >= 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try the `LdapDistinguishedNameEncode(string, bool, bool)` overload. Taken from [AntiXSS 4.0 Released](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/securitytools/2010/09/30/antixss-4-0-released/):

> **LdapDistinguishedNameEncode(string, bool, bool)** is also provided so you may turn off the initial or final character escaping rules, for example if you are concatenating the escaped distinguished name fragment into the midst of a complete distinguished name.

Hope it helps!

Comment: While good advice for my sample code this doesn't fix the problem because the problematic characters are in the middle of the OU name.  I've updated the question with examples.